# Summon item not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making an adventure map, and at some points I need there to be items on the ground. But when I use the `/summon` command, it always ends up as a stone block.

Here's what I've used:

```
/summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:276,Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"Mirage"},Unbreakable:1},Damage:0}}
```

This did not work, so I tried a simpler command:

```
/summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:276,Count:1,tag:{},Damage:0}}
```

Which also summoned a stone block.
Please note that I am in the Minecraft 1.9 snapshot 16w05b

Comment: Your question was an answer to my question. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minecraft - Executing on an entity is not working](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224779/minecraft-executing-on-an-entity-is-not-working)

Answer (score 6):

#### Item number 276 does not exist in 1.9

Minecraft slowly moved away from numeric IDs for items for some time now, mostly because they are a hassle to remember. While previous versions such as 1.8 still allowed you to use numerical ids, you *have* to use the named ids starting with 1.9.

In your case, that is `minecraft:diamond_sword`, e.g.:

```
/summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:minecraft:diamond_sword,Count:1}}
```

Comment: Oh, they finally got rid of them entirely? That's nice, but hurts character counts in huge commands (i.e. one command block creations).

Comment: No, vestiges of numeric IDs still existed for two more years after this answer was posted, only to be finally removed in 1.13.

Comment: "minecraft:diamond_sword" needs to be quoted.